# Email with rich-text formatting

Tags: php, email

I need to know if there is any way to increase the font size and make fonts in bold in my email message. I am using `text/plain` as my content type. I don't need to use `text/html`. At the moment the whole of my message displays in same font size.

My message is something like this:

```
// initialize the $message variable
   $message = '';
    $message  = "You have recieved a new message from your web profile.\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "Hello, Mr. Jone Doe\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "As you already know, once you have joined with website and have published your details there.\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "Your profile page :\r\n";
    $message .= "www.mywebsite.com?code=2500&name=tharaga+nuwan\r\n\r\n";

   etc..................
```

Comment: you have to use text/html and add a inline style for each item you want bold or whatnot. or use <b>

Comment: as soon as you say plain you mean no changing ....

Comment: "`text/plain`" === **plain text**. As in "no formatting, just text".

Comment: seems people are voting to close this because "it is difficult to tell what is being asked here" - really? Isn't it quite easy to tell what is being asked here?

Comment: Emails were originally meant to be plain text. Formatting is usually done with HTML emails, a later aberration. For some nostalgia, see the outdated [Why HTML in E-Mail is a Bad Idea](http://archive.birdhouse.org/etc/evilmail.html)

Comment: thanks for all response. But I don't know why I got down votes for this...

Comment: @ugnuku I haven't downvoted myself, but your question `does not show any research effort`. This is a very basic issue, for which you can easily find multiple references and background material. See the always relevant [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @ugnuku you got down votes because this type of questions are already asked by others, dont worry let me give you +1 vote for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plain text doesn't have ways to specify font sizes, bolds etc (as don't regular *.txt files). You'd need to use HTML or RTF for that.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `text/html` for that, or else you can not format the text.

Then add `<b> your text</b>` for bold

I recommend you to use `php mailer class`, there you can specify the content type and other settings

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `text/html` and  then use `<b>` or `<strong>` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
   $to   = receipent@domain.com;
   $from = sender@domain.com; 

   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
   $headers  .= "From: $from\r\n";


   $message = '';
   $message  = "You have recieved a new message from your web profile.\r\n\r\n";
   $message .= "Hello, <span style='font-size:12px;font-weight:bold'>Mr. Jone   Doe</span>\r\n\r\n";
```

User these header in your mail() function. With these headers you can use any type of HTML in your Email message.

Happy Coding