# Sending a confirmation message automatically to a given email id in form

Tags: php, html, css

I need to send confirmation email to the user who fill form and it sends rich text..

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: ? use mail function? maybe

Comment: I assume you want to know how to send an e-mail via PHP? Do you know that StackOverflow has a search function (upper right hand corner)? This question has been answered already several times.

Comment: i need to know how i can use autoresponse as a rich text sending and if i need any attachment to send with email how i can do it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just one line away from sending the mail. Use the PHP mail function.

```
    $from = "youraddress@example.com";
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Auto reply - HR Consultants Pakistan";
    $message = "Dear $name, \n\n Thank you for your registration. We will Get back to you Soon. \n \n If you have any questions, you can call us on \n \n ";
    mail( $to, $subject, $message);
```

Suggestion: please SEARCH before you question. You'll get this easily by googling.

Comment: i have completed this but i need to know how i can send rich text in mail autoresponder.

Comment: You mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197248/email-with-rich-text-formatting

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanGhani You have to learn more about PHP Mail, you need to set headers for a rich text and attachment.